# Compress video from UIImagePickerController at a later time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, video, compression

I was wondering if anyone has suggestions on how to compress a video that is recorded/selected with a UIImagePickerController, at a later time.

---

Scenario:

User picks or records a video at Medium quality.  I later upload this video to my server.  However, I would like to check at the time of uploading whether the user is on 3G or Wifi, and transcode/compress to a lower quality at that time if needed.

---

I understand that I could specify the quality when I display the picker, but it would provide more flexibility if I could grab the clip in a higher quality format, and then only compress later if needed.

I haven't been able to find any way to do this in the Apple docs, and have also been unable to find any 3rd party libs for video compression.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apple don't provide any sort of libraries for transcoding videos - but I'm surprised you haven't been able to find and 3rd party libraries. FFMPEG is the library of choice. Now, it is in C, but it's perfectly usable and workable on iOS. Note that there are some LGPL things you have to be aware of when using FFMPEG.

Note that transcoding is an expensive process, especially in terms of CPU usage, so this may not actually be the best option. Better to let iOS handle it for you where at all possible.